# Exported glTF not the same as my model

Tags: export, gltf

I exported my model as an extended glTF file but the glTF file looks wrong. The arrays do not exist (there is only the initial object displaying) and they appear above other objects.
What could cause this?

I realise that (it seems to be) related only to exporting to extended glTF which is an addon (msfs toolkit) but I wondered if someone reading this has any ideas.

Here are images of the original 'project' and the object imported from the glTF file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tick _Geometry > Apply Modifiers_ on the glTF export screen.

Comment: Thanks for that. I watched a youtube video on creation of 3d objects in Blender for MSFS and the author showed lots of  parts of the glTF export screen which needed ticking or entering and did NOT mention that. IO get heaps of help watching these video tutorials but they often either assume things or don't cover everything.  Thanks again.